# Remove Gmail AI buttons

Tags: gmail

We send our clients some emails, Some of our Gmail clients sees these buttons "yes, I confirm." "Yes, I approve." and "I don't agree"

[image: screenshot for buttons]

Which is not appropriate to the content of our message

How can I remove them from my side? Is there any code/tag that I can add to my email message to stop this buttons from showing up?
What does Google name this buttons/feature to find/search more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I remove them from my side?

You can't.

> Is there any code/tag that I can add to my email message to stop this buttons from showing up?

No.

> What does Google name this buttons/feature to find/search more about it?

[Smart Reply](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/smart-reply).

Comment: Thank you, your reply was very helpful, it was great that you can answer my question before StackOverflow close it